# How to check for the current active category in Shopware 6 with Twig?

Tags: twig, shopware

I'm using Shopware 6 and need to check for a the **current active** category name in a Twig condition?

Something like this:

```
{% if page.header.navigation.active.category == 'Books' %}
    <h1>yes</h1>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Be aware that changing the name might break your functionality. What are you trying to achieve..maybe a flag attribute for the category might be a better way

Comment: Yes I know that a name change would break it. Basically I'm trying just to hide / show things on the product detail page.

Answer (score 1):

On the product detail page the category can be found in `page.product.seoCategory`. To check category by name:

```
{% if page.product.seoCategory.translated.name == 'Books' %}
    <h1>yes</h1>
{% endif %}
```

On all other pages you can use the variable `page.header.navigation.active`:

```
{% if page.header.navigation.active.translated.name == 'Books' %}
    <h1>yes</h1>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: The second example works – thanks!
Although with the first example I get "null". Do I have to edit / activate something in the Shopware Backend?

Comment: The first example works only on product detail page. This works always if product is assigned to a category, no additional configuration is required in the backend. Can you dump the variable for example in the template `storefront/page/product-detail/index.html.twig` with `{{ dump(page.product.seoCategory) }}`? Does it output `null`?

Comment: Yes i dump it in that file and it returns **null**